# tables are not reflecting on database on vs 2013 by using code first approach of EF 6.1

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-migrations, visual-studio-2013

I have created model classes and using following context in my mvc project on VS2013 and using EF 6.1

```
public class DataBase : DbContext
    {
     public class DataBase : DbContext
            {
                public DataBase()
                    : base("Db")
                {
                }

      public DbSet<table> table{ get; set; }
        }
    }
"Db" is my connection string everything ,everything run good but table are not created on my database
```

Comment: Please post your connection string.

Comment: Have you removed your login information from connection string,or is it missing?(Do not post the login info here)As you have integrated security=false and no username/password I would expect you to get an exception because you can't login to the db and hence not make changes to it.But you didn't get any exceptions?When you call your DbContext (ie getting all table records), in debug mode, can you check if the dbcontext is properly initialized? And verify that the connstring is what you expect? Also, you should remove the Data Source url from comment (not from connstring), just to be safe.

Comment: yes, connection string is working since i created table manually in database and accessing it,,,but i want this should done by EF

Comment: Are you sure that ef is accessing your database and not the localDb?

Comment: yes i'm sure since am looking at my database at server ,where i manually created my tables

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
public class DataBase : DbContext
{
 public class DataBase : DbContext
        {
            public DataBase()
                : base("Name=Db")
            {
            }

  public DbSet<table> table{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Set `:base()` to "Name=Db".

Comment: I tried this just right now but still database is not showing my table

Answer (score 0):

In ef 6 they changed how things work and therefore you need to do some manual steps to be able to generate the database. You have a couple of options I think:

1. Use the packed manager console and run the Update-DataBase command. (You'll have to figure out which flags to use) This might require you to make a blank db with the expected name before running update.

2. Change your database initializer command to:

```
Database.SetInitializer<UserDbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<UserDbContext, Configuration>());
```

This should make your code always update/create the database. Probably not what you want for production environment though..

3. You create your own initializer, which also has the benefit of seeding data to database on creation. Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application <-- towards the end of the article there is an example of such an initializer. The chapter heading is "Set up EF to initialize the database with test data"

Comment: i'm getting this error on by Update-Database command in package manager console..System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy' from assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

Comment: Hmm.. might be that you either miss some flag or that not all your dlls implement entity framework 6 but rather some older version. Please confirm that you have the right versions of ef and that they are correctly referred in web.config